Can I ramp between various hardwood flooring levels instead of using a transition strip?
I have few different thicknesses of hardwood in the house--just what the last owner did. I’m redoing a part of the flooring and I’m on two levels. Effectively half the house has extra layer of plywood underneath the hardwood. So, there is a 5/8 inch difference in height that was previously managed by a transition piece.
Can I slowly build up to a 5/8 height of plywood?  Like build a ramp- so no transition piece is needed? I can do this ramp over 5 feet. So about 1/8 height increase per foot.
This wood be in the hallway, and the hardwood runs perpendicular to the hallway.
Hopefully this is all clear. Any thoughts?
I know best is to rip it all out or just do a transition strip and move on, but figured I would ask.
Thanks.

You don't say how wide is this ramp will be. Whatever you do, you'd still end up with a joint to contend with at the base and at the top.

Right, good point. It wouldn’t be flat so some joint will be there.
The ramp is like hallway width- so like 34 inches or thereabouts.

Such ramps usually look good, but work terrible. Basically, you don't see the ramp (which is the goal here), so you forget about the ramp, so you trip every time you walk on it.

@Jakesb, please take the [tour] so you know how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

I guess you could get some 6' strips of 5/8" wood and rip them diagonally (assuming 1/8" kerf) -- you'll probably want to contract that out unless you have a table saw and a suitable sled.

Believe it or not, a 5/8" ramp even over 5 feet is noticeable, but to the feet, not to the eyes. It'll feel awkward to anyone not intimately familiar with the home, and they probably won't see it. It could even cause tripping with grippy footwear.
Also, it's more difficult than it may seem to achieve flatness when doing something like that. When light is at a low angle you're likely to see ripples or unevenness in the floor.
For those reasons, a single step of 5/8" (or that plus the thickness of an overlay flange) that's visually conspicuous is preferrable.
